# Parameter estimation for time-varying autoregressive processes in R

Tags: r, time-series, stochastic-processes, autoregressive

I want to estimate the parameters of an autoregressive process with time-dependent coefficients. For example TVAR(1) model with 1 lag:  $$ X_t = \phi_t X_{t-1} + \sigma_tW_t $$ where $\phi_t$ and $\sigma_t$ are time-dependent and $W_t$ is the standard Wiener process. I could do this with the tvAR package if the stochastic scaling $\sigma_t$ were constant but I need to assume it is not.

So my question is, how can I best fit autoregressive models in R that have time-varying volatility?